# What's the best way to add a derived field onto a Doctrine_Record subclass?

Tags: php, doctrine

Imagine I have a table called "item" that has a column called "price". In addition to the full price, I'd like to get the price spread across 12 months, i.e.,

```
class Item extends Doctrine_Record {
  ...
  public function getMonthlyPrice() {
    return $this->price/12;
  }
}
```

Now, say I'd like to have Item act like the monthly price is just another column rather than a function call, e.g.,

```
$m = Doctrine_Core::getTable("Item")->find(1);
echo $m->price; //prints 120
echo $m->monthlyPrice; //prints 10
```

My first instinct is to override the __get() method. Is there a better or more standard way to do this in Doctrine?

---

**Bonus question:**

Is there some very clever way I can rig the object so when I do

```
var_dump($m->getData())
```

I see

```
array
  'price' => 120
  'monthlyPrice' => 10
```

*That* would be pretty nifty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian said you could do this with filters, but there is another way which I think is closer to what you're looking for - you'd need to enable Doctrine's ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE feature, which means that it will check for methods in the form get* and set* which match your property call them automatically. Here's an example:

```
class Example extends Doctrine_Record {

    public function getFoo() {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);

$example = new Example();
echo $example->foo;
```

As to the second part of your question, not that I've seen - your best bet is to override the method in your models as appropriate, or create a subclass of Doctrine_Record that your models then extend which has a single override that wraps up that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is Record Filters. I don't really know Doctrine, I primarily use Propel myself; but this sounds like it might accomplish what you need:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/pl#record-filters